# performing comparative calculation for classes within csv

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, collections, dictionary

I am trying to perform a relatively simple calculation for groups of data within a csv. I have a feeling the function I need to be using is contained within the collections lib, but having been through the documentation for this library several times (http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html). I cannot work out how to use this library in order to achieve my desired output. Perhaps there is another way?

What I need to do (efficiently) is; for each `Uniqueclasselement` group identify the largest number in column 4 (zero based column reference.) Then for each row within that group calculate the difference between this "large" number and the number for column 4 in this row. For the first three rows in `Uniqueclasselement1` it would be, `6` `15` & `2` (111 minus 105,96 & 109 respectively). Then I would need to add this number to the number in column `2` and append the result to a new column within this csv.

#### Example data:

```
data,Uniqueclasselement1,52,data,105
data,Uniqueclasselement1,58,data,96
data,Uniqueclasselement1,59,data,109
data,Uniqueclasselement1,42,data,111
data,Uniqueclasselement1,32,data,107
data,Uniqueclasselement1,49,data,105
data,Uniqueclasselement1,50,data,104
data,Uniqueclasselement1,51,data,89
data,Uniqueclasselement1,79,data,99
data,Uniqueclasselement2,69,data,105
data,Uniqueclasselement2,58,data,96
data,Uniqueclasselement2,88,data,109
data,Uniqueclasselement2,84,data,111
data,Uniqueclasselement2,90,data,107
data,Uniqueclasselement2,55,data,105
data,Uniqueclasselement2,56,data,104
data,Uniqueclasselement2,79,data,89
data,Uniqueclasselement2,79,data,99
data,Uniqueclasselement3,63,data,105
data,Uniqueclasselement3,66,data,96
data,Uniqueclasselement3,69,data,109
data,Uniqueclasselement3,72,data,111
data,Uniqueclasselement3,52,data,107
data,Uniqueclasselement3,89,data,105
data,Uniqueclasselement3,70,data,104
data,Uniqueclasselement3,91,data,89
data,Uniqueclasselement3,79,data,99
```

#### Desired results

```
data,Uniqueclasselement1,52,data,105,58
data,Uniqueclasselement1,58,data,96,73
data,Uniqueclasselement1,59,data,109,61
data,Uniqueclasselement1,42,data,111,42
data,Uniqueclasselement1,32,data,107,36
data,Uniqueclasselement1,49,data,105,55
data,Uniqueclasselement1,50,data,104,57
data,Uniqueclasselement1,51,data,89,73
data,Uniqueclasselement1,79,data,99,91
data,Uniqueclasselement2,69,data,105,81
data,Uniqueclasselement2,58,data,96,79
data,Uniqueclasselement2,88,data,109,96
data,Uniqueclasselement2,84,data,117,84
data,Uniqueclasselement2,90,data,107,100
data,Uniqueclasselement2,55,data,105,67
data,Uniqueclasselement2,56,data,104,69
data,Uniqueclasselement2,79,data,89,107
data,Uniqueclasselement2,79,data,99,97
data,Uniqueclasselement3,63,data,105,67
data,Uniqueclasselement3,66,data,96,79
data,Uniqueclasselement3,69,data,109,69
data,Uniqueclasselement3,72,data,101,80
data,Uniqueclasselement3,52,data,107,54
data,Uniqueclasselement3,89,data,105,93
data,Uniqueclasselement3,70,data,104,75
data,Uniqueclasselement3,91,data,89,111
data,Uniqueclasselement3,79,data,99,89
```

I have defined the whole task i wish to undertake, not so you the stackoverflow community provide me with the entire code, but to define the scene of what I am trying to achieve. It was mentioned in the comments that this could potentially be 1 line of code in pandas. I have just spent 3 hours watching pandas tutorials on youtube, and I am none the wiser on how to perform said calculations for each uniqueclasselement for this csv. I would really appreciates some constructive comments or directions rather than the standard "what have you tried" brigade.

Comment: it is a one-liner with [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)

Comment: For real? Thanks for Link am looking now

Comment: Perhaps I shouldn't have defined the entire task, I have done this mainly to set the scene.

Answer (score 4):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('inputfile.csv', header=None, sep=',')

df[5] = df.groupby(1)[4].transform(max)-df[4]+df[2]

df.to_csv('test.csv', header=False)
```

Comment: If this code works I will award a 50 point bounty, as well as adding a couple of new methods to my coding repertoire! (It almost looks too simple!) Thanks for the reply! (pre testing)